# Caps lock rebound to ctrl generates Ctrl-Shift in emacs

Tags: emacs

I've rebound my caps lock key to be an additional ctrl key, but in emacs using the rebound key generates the C-S key combination. Pressing caps-p generates the sequence C-S-p, whereas using the the ctrl key to do the same generates C-p.

This results in some weird behaviour, such as C-n and C-p setting a mark and then highlighting the region that I go through.

I have not changed the definition of the caps key in X, instead using the setting built into my window manager (Cinnamon). Could this be what is causing the problem, or is this the intended behaviour of this key?

Comment: You don't need to rebind caps lock to have that effect, I think. I have that same effect, whenever caps lock is activated, C-p C-n become C-s-p. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about how the keyboard is handled to point to a proper solution.
There are some pointers (and an ugly solution) here http://emacs.1067599.n5.nabble.com/Re-bug-7637-24-0-50-Caps-Lock-triggers-set-mark-command-td119922.html

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem before, my keyboard has problem with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key. Maybe you have the same problem.

Comment: I suspect you're going to have to dig in a little further. I'd start with some basic tools: xev will tell you what keycodes are being generated when you press the key. xmodmap will let you add and remove modifiers. Between the two of them, you should be able to experiment a bit and figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26946/disabling-caps-lock-by-setxkbmap-makes-it-shift-key-in-emacs) question is probably relevant, basically just use xmodmap to set the keys directly. It worked for me when I had caps lock set to control and I think I was using gnome3 classic (which Cinammon is based on) at the time.

On a related note I'd also recommend having a look at [space2ctrl](https://github.com/r0adrunner/Space2Ctrl), I found that reaching for caps lock all the time still hurt my fingers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running CrunchBang 10 "Statler" (derived from Debian 6 "Squeeze") on an Asus laptop
(yeah, I'm a little behind right now)

I've currently got GNU Emacs 23.2.1. It didn't even recognize the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key as a keypress until I re-mapped it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> using xmodmap.

So first I created file ~/.Xmodmap:

```
! attempting to redefine the <Caps Lock> key to do <Ctrl>                      
remove Lock = Caps_Lock                                                        
add Control = Caps_Lock
```

Apparently Debian uses .xsession, vs..xinitrc.

file .xsession is where the window manager (Openbox) gets started with exec
I inserted the xmodmap call before the exec:

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                      
# gonna modify the keys so <Caps Lock> is <Ctrl>                               
xmodmap /home/tom/.Xmodmap

exec openbox-session
```

The <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key seems to be working just like the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key
within Emacs now.